# Drawtext freezes

Tags: python, ffmpeg, drawtext

I am trying to add text to a 1 hour long video but to a specified time only . I used this command from within python and used subprocess to run it.

```
   cmd="ffmpeg -y -i "+input_file+" -vf drawtext=enable=\'between(t,"+str(start)+","+str(end)+")\':fontfile=C\:\\\\\\\\ffmpeg\\\\\\\\arial.ttf\:text="+starttime+"\:x="+endtime+"\:y="+str(i[3][1])+" "+output.mp4
    print(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), shell=True,
                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = p.communicate()[0]
```

When I try running this the whole process freezes in the shell that is it prints the cmd and nothing happens

```
ffmpeg -y -i C:\\moviepy-master\\moviepy-master\\lecture7.mp4 -vf drawtext=enable='between(t,300,1000)':fontfile=C\:\\\\ffmpeg\\\\arial.ttf\:text=helloworld\:x=200\:y=600 C:\\moviepy-master\\moviepy-master\\lecture7text.mp4,
```

The whole process takes a very long time and the final video does not have the text at all .

Comment: Does it run directly from the command line?

Comment: No, this runs from within a python module hence the subprocess call

Comment: Yes, but does it run directly from the command line?

Comment: yes, when i run it for shorter length videos it works fine ,when i say shorter length i am talking about 7 minutes or so .